# Frame around two Latex Pictures, Heading on top

Tags: tikz-trees

so what I want is to have two boxed with LaTex pictures (5 in the left box, two in the right) next to each other who each have a different heading.
I didn't manage to even put the text on top of the LaTex pictures without having them below each other or some other bug.

This is what my code looks like currently:

```
    \documentclass[
  a4paper,               % A4-Papier
  twoside,               % zweiseitig
  DIV=12,                % Zwölfteilung der Seite
  BCOR=8mm,              % 8mm Korrektur für Bindung
  headinclude=true,      % Header hinzufügen
  footinclude=false,     % Footer nicht hinzufügen
  numbers=noenddot,      % keine Punkte nach Kapitelnummern
  headheight=40pt,       % Höhe des Header-Blocks
  11pt]  {scrartcl}      % Schriftgröße
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% Weitere interessante Pakete:
% stmaryrd, mathpazo, MnSymbol, shadethm, xy, setspace, listings, color,
% colortbl, hyperref, fancyvrb, moreverb, tocloft, ulem
% Keine Einrückung am Anfang eines Absatzes
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\section*{Aufgabe 1}
\subsection*{a)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \node (1) {1. //A//B/F};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm}] 
  \node (R1) {$\mathrm{A_1}$} 
                child {node  {$\mathrm{C_1}$}
                      child {node  {$\mathrm{B_1}$} 
                            child{node{$\mathrm{F_2}$}}}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}                                     
  \node (R2) {$\mathrm{A_2}$} 
                child {node  {$\mathrm{C_3}$}
                      child {node  {$\mathrm{B_2}$} 
                            child {node{$\mathrm{F_3}$}}
                      }
                }
                child {node{$\mathrm{G_1}$}
                      child {node{$\mathrm{B_3}$}
                            child {node{$\mathrm{F_3}$}
                            }
                      }
                };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}                                     
  \node (R2) {$\mathrm{A_5}$} 
                child {node  {$\mathrm{Z_1}$}
                      child {node  {$\mathrm{B_6}$} 
                            child {node{$\mathrm{E_2}$}
                                child {node{$\mathrm{B_{10}}$}
                                      child {node{$\mathrm{F_5}$}
                                      }
                                }
                            }
                      }
                };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}                                     
  \node (R2) {$\mathrm{A_6}$} 
                child {node  {$\mathrm{B_5}$}
                      child {node  {$\mathrm{F_4}$}}
                };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \node (1) {2. //A/C//B/E};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}                                     
  \node (R2) {$\mathrm{A_2}$} 
                child {node  {$\mathrm{C_3}$}
                      child {node  {$\mathrm{B_2}$}
                            child {node  {$\mathrm{E_1}$}}
                      }
                };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}                                     
  \node (R2) {$\mathrm{A_5}$} 
                child {node  {$\mathrm{Z_1}$}
                      child {node  {$\mathrm{B_6}$} 
                            child {node{$\mathrm{E_2}$}
                                child {node{$\mathrm{B_{10}}$}
                                      child {node{$\mathrm{F_5}$}
                                      }
                                }
                            }
                      }
                };
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\\
3. Join aus 1. und 2. ergibt:
\begin{tikzpicture}                                     
  \node (R2) {$\mathrm{A_2}$} 
                child {node  {$\mathrm{C_3}$}
                      child {node  {$\mathrm{B_2}$}
                            child {node  {$\mathrm{E_1}$}}
                      }
                };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So simplified I have a few trees in multiple tikz pictures who are displayed next to each other at the moment but instead of having the text on the bottom left of the "picture group" I would like for the text to be on top and have a box around the corresponding trees.

I hope someone understands what I mean and can help me out

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Could you make it a bit more minimal? I bet you don't need `graphicx` or `babel` for the trees you are drawing. To answer your question, you can use `\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}\centering Text for first.\par\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}\end{minipage}%comment line break\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}\centering Text for second.\par\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}\end{minipage}`. This is if the text isn't captions. If it is, then you can use `capt-of` or `caption` and the `\captionof` if you don't want them to float.

Comment: Off topic: Don't break lines using `\\ ` unless you are in a `tabular` or `array` or similar.  Your question asks about 7 pictures. But I don't really understand which you want where. What is next to what exactly? Does the frame go around 5 and another around 2? Or 7 frames? And the last picture is on its own?

Comment: I get 4 trees then 2 trees. Then 1 tree underneath the 4 trees. Should the 1 tree be beside the 4 trees? But that doesn't make sense it if has its own label.